# AngularJS - Calling a callback function with directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I cannot figure out why my directive is not calling my callback function from my parent page. Can you please assist?

Angular code:

```
    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .directive('testDirective', function () {
            return {
                bindToController: {
                    foo: '@',
                    myCallback: '&'
                },
                controller: function () {
                },
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                restrict: 'E',
                replace: true,
                scope: {},
                template: '<div>Foo is: {{ vm.foo }} <button data-ng-click="vm.myCallback()">Click to call Callback</button></div>'
            };
        });

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .controller('ParentController', function () {
            this.myParentCallback = function () {
                alert('Called the parent callback function');
            };
        });
```

HTML code:

```
<body>
    <div data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="ParentController as ctrl">
        <test-directive foo="bar!" my-callback="ctrl.myParentCallBack"></test-directive>
    </div>
</body>
```

As you can see, `foo` binds correctly, but I can't get `myCallback` to work...

Thoughts?

Here it is in plnkr: (http://plnkr.co/edit/niVL5iAeOJ6XTpkpL9fu?p=preview)

Comment: check this    my-callback="ctrl.myParentCallBack()" . not sure.

Comment: Thanks @Roy.23. This refers to the function `myParentCallback` which exists in `ParentController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a case problem: pass ctrl.myParentCall**b**ack with lowercase b in the callback.

Also, your plnkr has a bug, with vm.myParentCallBack. Replace with:

```
<test-directive foo="bar!" my-callback="ctrl.myParentCallback()"></test-directive>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/VnMUekTSZyk5WagsPqkL

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually call the myParentCallBack method on your ParentController. Like so:

```
<test-directive foo="bar!" my-callback="ctrl.myParentCallBack()"></test-directive>
```

This enables you to pass on $event or such as you wish.

Edit:
You also need to change your testDirective definition:

```
return {
    bindToController: true,
    controller: function () {},
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        foo: '@',
        myCallback: '&'
    },
    template: '<div>Foo is: {{ vm.foo }} <button data-ng-click="vm.myCallback()">Click to call Callback</button></div>'
};
```

Changes are that you just tell that you want to use bindToController (by specifying it with true) and are specifying the properties with the scope property of your directive definition. You mixed them up.

Comment: Thanks @BasSlagter. I tried this, however it did not work. I didn't receive any error either. Any thoughts?

Comment: Thanks @BasSlagter. I replaced my code with yours exactly, and still it does not work. Any thoughts here?

Comment: Maybe you can create a fiddle/plnkr?

Comment: Thanks @BasSlagter. Here it is: (http://plnkr.co/edit/niVL5iAeOJ6XTpkpL9fu?p=preview)